# Extra TD space added in Bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, angular6

Using Angular 6 to display data, when I have a td row with a custom message, my Bootstrap table inserts an extra empty td after it, creating unwanted space.  The row with "test" pushes "EDIT" out of line.  Appreciate any suggestions.
Link to image of the issue...
https://ibb.co/WP7tMJr

```css
table.teacherTable tr {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 50px 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

td {
  padding-right: 65px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

td.redText {
  color: rgb(211, 32, 32);
  font-size: 13px;
}

th {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#teacherTableList {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

p {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="teacherTableList">
  <p>Students Checked In/Out Today... </p>
  <table class="teacherTable" id="">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th>Check In Time</th>
        <th>Check Out Time</th>
        <th>Edit Student Session</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let tod of studentsInToday">

        <td>{{ tod.classTimesStudentName }} </td>
        <td>{{ tod.classTimesSubjects }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="!tod.classTimesLogInRevised">{{ tod.classTimesLogInDate | date: 'medium' }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="tod.classTimesLogInRevised">{{ tod.classTimesLogInRevised | date: 'medium' }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="!tod.classTimesLogOffDate  && !tod.classTimesLogOffRevised" class="redText"> test</td>
        <td *ngIf="!tod.classTimesLogOffRevised">{{ tod.classTimesLogOffDate | date: 'medium' }}</td>
        <td *ngIf="tod.classTimesLogOffRevised">{{ tod.classTimesLogOffRevised | date: 'medium' }}</td>
        <td><a [routerLink]="['/teacher/teacheredit/', tod.classTimesRowId]">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like that is exactly what you coded. You are inside a loop and conditionally outputting the columns so if the dataset has enough variation you are sure to get different number of columns in each row which is invalid HTML. I would suggest making the `<td>` structure fixed inside the loop and move the `ngIf` logic to some new element like a `<div>` inside each of the columns so the data is conditionally displayed without disrupting the HTML table markup.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I'm not sure what you mean by the "<td> structure" ?  It appears (to me) inside the loop already. I tried moving the ngIf to a div, it did not help.